# How can I use a variable set in iOS "Shortcuts" in the REST app?

Tags: ios, rest, sirishortcuts

I am trying to create a "shortcuts" on iOS (phone) that takes any text from one specific sender, parses the text (a few text.split), then uses the [REST app](https://apps.apple.com/dk/app/rest-http-api-client/id1318172341?uo=4&itscg=30200&itsct=apps_box&mt=8) to make a POST with that parsed text.

I think I've figured out most of it, but not how to write the REST part so it takes a variable passed from the "shortcuts".

Basically, I want this as the body:

```
{"state":"on", "attributes":{"message":$VARIABLE}}
```

where $VARIABLE is the text (stored in a variable in "shortcuts") I want to pass. Any idea how to do this?